# Change black to some other color when printing?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, printing, canon-pixma, color-printer

I'm printing a reference for something that I will trace. However, the outline is colored black and our printer's black ink is out. So what I want to do is replace black with another color (e.g. violet) from the printer settings. How do I do this? The printer is Canon PIXMA MP250 and is on OS X 10.6.

Comment: Does the printer even print anything without black ink?